# Inserting variable into bash script mongodb command heredoc

Tags: bash, mongodb

I am running some commands to mongodb in a bash script but need to insert a string into a heredoc text. I am unable to get the value inserted correctly. How would this be done?

```
today=`date -d "00:00:00" +%s`
todaytime=$(($today*1000))
mongo <<EOF > test
    use log
    db.translogs.remove("{Dt: {$lt: new Date($todaytime)}}")
    exit
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know [mongodb](/questions/tagged/mongodb), but it looks like [`$lt` is part of a query](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/lt/#op._S_lt) and not a shell variable.  But in your code, the shell is trying to expand it before passing the here-doc to `mongo`.  So I think all you need to do is escape the `$` in `$lt`:

```
today=`date -d "00:00:00" +%s`
todaytime=$(($today*1000))
mongo  test
    use log
    db.translogs.remove("{Dt: {\$lt: new Date($todaytime)}}")
    exit
EOF
```

If I replace `mongo` with `cat` in the above code, we see the commands-to-be-sent to `mongo` in the `test` file as:

```
    use log
    db.translogs.remove("{Dt: {$lt: new Date(1393315200000)}}")
    exit
```